# Webpage looks different on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, prefixfree

I have a webpage but it looks different on different browsers. Even the amount of padding and margin I gave are way off and let's not talk about the JS stuff.
I also have it live here: 
**https://iam-shivam.github.io/DrumPad/drumpad.html**

 How do I make sure that they look the same on all browsers? Some way to automate this or manual tips?
I even tried a prefix-free script, but it didn't seem to do any good. Maybe I'm using it wrong. Here's the link:
http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

**HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Virtual DrumPad</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\drumpad.css">
    <link rel="prefetch" href="sounds\">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/gh-pages/plugins/prefixfree.jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row middle">
            <div class="header" style="">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="300px" height="118px">
            </div>
            <div class="container col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 buttonGroup">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 big">

                        <button data-key="65" class="drumpad">A<br><sub>CLAP</sub></</button>

                        <button data-key="83" class="drumpad">S<br><sub>HIHAT</sub></</button>

                        <button data-key="68" class="drumpad">D<br><sub>KICK</sub></</button>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 big">

                        <button data-key="70" class="drumpad">F<br><sub>OPENHAT</sub></</button>

                        <button data-key="71" class="drumpad">G<br><sub>BOOM</sub></</button>

                        <button data-key="72" class="drumpad">H<br><sub>RIDE</sub></button>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 big">

                        <button data-key="74" class="drumpad">J<br><sub>SNARE</sub></</button>

                        <button data-key="75" class="drumpad">K<br><sub>TOM</sub></</button>

                        <button data-key="76" class="drumpad">L<br><sub>TINK</sub></button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="scripts\jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function playIt(e){
            var keys = document.querySelector('[data-key="'+e.keyCode+'"]');
            if(keys == null)return;
            mainStuff(keys);
        }

        function mainStuff(keys){
            keys.classList.add('playing');
            var sname = keys.querySelector('sub').innerHTML.toLowerCase();
            var audio = new Audio("sounds\\"+sname+".wav");
            audio.play();

            keys.addEventListener('transitionend',function(){
                keys.classList.remove('playing');
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener('keydown',playIt);
        var all = document.querySelectorAll('.drumpad');
        all.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('click', function(){
            mainStuff(this);
        }));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS File:**

```
:root {
    --bcolor: black;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.middle {
    background-image: url('../images/background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    border-left: 4px solid var(--bcolor);
    border-right: 4px solid var(--bcolor);
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.drumpad {
    padding: 8%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
    background-color: #020202;
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.6);
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    transition: all 0.07s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.07s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.07s;
    -o-transition: all 0.07s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.07s;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
.playing ,
 .drumpad:active {
    background-color: #020202;
    background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.8);
    border: 2px solid #1A0000;
    border: 2px solid rgba(26, 0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
}
.big {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.buttonGroup {
    margin-top: 3%;
}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .buttonGroup button{
        padding: 10%;
    }
    .buttonGroup{
        margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .drumpad{
        margin: 1%;
        width: 120px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty normal to have UIs look different between browsers. Thats one of the harder parts of being a UI developer. If I had to take a few educated guesses I'd say that `float`ing inside a `flex` will cause some weirdness. I would also stay away from percentage padding and margin.

Comment: This is not a solution but it might be helpful to you. Add min-height and min-width (if possible) to the element which will prevent various width/height between browsers.